# I forgot my root password

Tags: password, accounts

How can I reset my password without knowing my password? I tried changing my password to a longer and harder password to crack and I wrote it down in a word file but now I lost the file and I can't remember my password. Does anyone know how to reset it? I need to know as soon as possible because it's nearly 5 am and I need to close my computer but I won't be able to log back in without knowing my password.

Comment: If you have physical access to the PC it is possible to force / change the password, but that will not give access to your data if your home directory if encrypted. *Answer to password reset already on this forum.*

Comment: Thank you! And i don't have much data anyways because this is a new pc that i install Ubuntu on, thanks for the help man! :D

Answer (score -1):

Boot an other Linux/Unix system. Mount your root-partition. Go to the mounted /way_to_mountpoint/etc. Edit the passwd, by deleting the x in the password field. Reboot your System in the normal way. Login as root, and change the root passwd in the normal way.

Comment: Please be more specific.